# executenonquery not working in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

In database:

```
Alter Procedure Update_MaterialTransactionsto2ForWithdrawal
  @materialName varchar(50),
  @staffNumber varchar(10),
  @description varchar(50),
  @transactionID int
As
Begin
   Update Table_MaterialTransactions
   set Status=2
   where StaffNumber = @staffNumber 
     and CrossSection = @description 
     and SubSubCategory = @materialName 
     and Status = 1 
     and TransactionID = @transactionID
End
```

In data access layer:

```
public static void UpdateMaterial(string staffNumber,string materialName,string description,int transaction)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectDatabase.ReturnConnectionString());
    //I am passing connection string as the parameter

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_MaterialTransactionsto2ForWithdrawal", connection);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@materialName", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = materialName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@staffNumber", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = staffNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@transactionID", SqlDbTypeInt).Value = transactionID;

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       connection.Close();
    }
```

On the client side:

```
void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   int j=0,k=0;

   for(int i=0;i<transactions.Count;i++)
   {
       string id = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$" + i.ToString();

       CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)Page.FindControl(id);

       if(chk.Checked == true)
       {
            Objects.UpdateMaterial(staffNumbers[i].ToString(), materials[i].ToString(), descriptions[i].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(transactions[i]));

            j++;
       }
       else
       {
            Objects.DeleteTheSelectedRowOfMaterialTransaction(staffNumbers[i].ToString(), materials[i].ToString(), descriptions[i].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(transactions[i]));

            k++;
        }
   }
```

I have check boxes in the table and when the user checks the check boxes and clicks submit, the boxes which are checked will update the database.

But the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is not executing and it is returning 0 rows. It is not throwing any error. But if I do this manually in the database, the stored procedure is working fine.

Kindly tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: where is ur staffNumbeer and othwer variable are declaired

Comment: I did not post the entire code...Thje staffNumbers which u r seeing in the client code is an arraylist..I checked in debugging,..Correct parameters are being passed to the query from web application. But the executenonquery is returning 0 rows affected. It is not throwing any error alse.

Comment: u have stff number size 50 while adding parameter and have size 10 in database....

Comment: does it make a difference..my staff number size is 7 which is <10

Comment: do u have any variable name transactionID in ur object class

Comment: Ya..I have it..It is declared as int...While debugging I checked the values of parameters in the data aceess layers..The values are correctly passed...But the command is not working..

Comment: you define transaction and pass  transactionID IN parameter in function

Comment: Remove try and catch block, you will get the error. The parameter values passing from your page may be different from the value which your are testing in sql editor.

Answer (score 0):

try adding last line in procedure

```
Return @@Rowcount
```

Comment: ok then use SQL profiler and check what was the update query exactly executed, by doing this you will come to know what is the issue with your update query.